# How to use async, await and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise, async-await

I am building a web scraper to get all of user's submissions on codeforces.
I don't know much about async, await, promises.
I have used axios (promise based) to request codeforces and  cheerio to parse HTML .

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const usernameorhandle = req.body.userName;
  getstatus(usernameorhandle).then ( ()=> {
      var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/Data/solutions.zip');
      var archive = archiver('zip', {
        zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
      });
      output.on('close', function() {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
      });
      output.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Data has been drained');
      });
      res.attachment(__dirname + "/Data/Problems", 'Codeforces-Solutions');
      archive.pipe(res);
      archive.directory(__dirname + "/Data/Problems", 'Codeforces-Solutions');
      archive.finalize();
    }) })
```

I am using to accept post request. 
I am putting all the solutions into a folder and creating zip folder and then send to res.

Below is my getstatus function.

```
    async function getstatus(handle){
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=> {
    console.log("HELLLLLLLOOOOOOOO");
    await axios.get("https://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=" + handle + "&from=1")
      .then(response => {
        if(response.data.status === 'OK'){
          let results = response.data.result;
          console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa");
          scrape(results).then( () =>{
            console.log("DONE");
            resolve();
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
          // resolve();
        }
        else console.log(submissions.comment);
      })
  })

}
```

I use scrape function to obtain HTML data and put to folder named Problems.

```
async function scrape (results){
  console.log("inside scrape");
  //  console.log("HELLO");
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
    await results.forEach(async (result)=> {
      if(result.verdict === 'OK'){
        await axios.get("https://codeforces.com/contest/" + result.contestId + "/submission/" + result.id)
        .then(solutionPage => {
          const $ = cheerio.load(solutionPage.data);
          const path = "/home/srujan/Desktop/crawlerapp/Data/Problems/" + result.problem.name + ".cpp";
           fs.writeFile(path, $('#program-source-text').text(), function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            else{
              console.log("Saved file");
            }
          })
        })
        .catch( error => {
          console.log("HTML PARSE ERROR" + error);
        })
     }
    })
    console.log("hey");
    resolve();

  })
```

The problem is I am getting

```
HELLLLLLLOOOOOOOO
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
inside scrape
hey
DONE
saved file
saved file
...
```

Browser downloads after DONE and then files are saved. 
I am new to js and don't know why I am getting this.

PS : I know this is very long question. I tried reading a lot about this. Didn't understand properly how to do that. I copy pasted some code which I didn't understand like how to zip a folder.

Comment: The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) are very helpful if you want to learn about async/await and promises.

Comment: I read but I don't what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Also, the res.attachment() method sets the ```Content-Disposition``` header in your response which makes your browser download the file. So it is intended behaviour. Is that not what you want to achieve?

Comment: But the browser starts downloading before the files are saved .

Comment: Yes it will start downloading as soon as the response is received completely, since the response has the ```Content-Disposition``` header.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I have used await to do finish the loop in scrape (to save all the files) and then the browser should start downloading right? because I resolve after the loop is finished. Then it goes to getstatus andresolve that also . Then it returns to post req and do the zip folder

Comment: await keyword will get you the result of a resolved promised, once it is resolved. It waits for the promise to resolve and only then the rest of program proceeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach(callback)` **executes** `callback`. If `callback` returns a promise (ie, it's an async function), the promise won't be resolved before calling the callback on the next element of the array.

So, basically, you can't use async functions inside forEach... But you can use for-loops or `Promise.all` instead!

Also, `fs.writeFile` works with sync + callback, but there exists a `fs.promise.writeFile` that uses promises instead.

Here's a scrape function that should work better:

```
async function scrape(results) {
  for (const result of results) {
    if(result.verdict === 'OK') {
      const solutionPage = await axios.get("https://codeforces.com/contest/" + result.contestId + "/submission/" + result.id);
      const $ = cheerio.load(solutionPage.data);
      const path = "/home/srujan/Desktop/crawlerapp/Data/Problems/" + result.problem.name + ".cpp";
      try {
        await fs.promises.writeFile(path, $('#program-source-text').text());
      } catch(err) { console.log(err) }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But the browser is downloading before writing the files and also again after writing? The first download has no content and the second time it's perfect. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to use result.forEach
Try to use a simple for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) without async.

If that doesn't work, try to return anything inside the then.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would construct `getstatus` function with await async

```js
 async function getstatus(handle) {

    const response = await axios.get("https://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=" + handle + "&from=1")

    if(response.data.status === 'OK') {

      let results = response.data.result;

      try {
        await scrape(results);
        console.log("DONE");
      }
      catch(error) {
      }

    }
}
```

and `scrape` function accordingly...

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function scrape (results) {
  results.forEach(async (result)=> {

   if(result.verdict === 'OK') {
    const solutionPage = await axios.get("https://codeforces.com/contest/" + result.contestId + "/submission/" + result.id)

    const $ = cheerio.load(solutionPage.data);
    const path = "/home/srujan/Desktop/crawlerapp/Data/Problems/" + result.problem.name + ".cpp";

    try {
      await fs.writeFile(path, $('#program-source-text').text())
      console.log("Saved file");
    }
    catch(error) {
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: fs.writeFile requires a callback so we can't use try catch. Also we can't use await before fs.writeFile when callback is used. Also browser downloads suddenly after getting post request before writing files .

Comment: You can change function with callback to promise using `util.promisify()` or look in the documentation is there is promise-like variant, here `require('fs').promises`. Well iam not sure if the latter is still supported